# Remove Path from the File Name of a Picture in VBA

Tags: vba

I know that their are already lots of similar questions to this but none of them seem to be giving me the answer i want.
I Have a power point to make that i am trying to automate so that VBA will automatically insert a picture for me. I use `GetOpenFileName` to allow the user to choose the file but as this is only supported in excel i have added excel to the list of references so the actual command is 
`Excel.Application.GetOpenFileName()`

My Sub therefore reads

```
Sub Image()
Dim Pict
Dim ImgFileFormat As String
ImgFileFormat = "Image Files (*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.bmp; *.gif; *.tif; *.tiff ), *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.bmp; *.gif; *.tif; *.tiff"
Pict = Excel.Application.GetOpenFilename(ImgFileFormat)
If Pict = False Then End
End Sub
```

What i want to do however is extract the name of the file from the file path (Pict Variable).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pict = Dir(Pict)
```

should give you only the file name.

Comment: Sweet!  Nice clean way to remove the path and leave just the file name.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for both awnseres but for me the simler the better

Comment: On thing to note: This works because you know the file actually exists.  Andrew's answer is more generic and works better if you have a path + filename, but don't yet know if it exists in the file system.

Comment: You coud trap nonexistent files like so, maybe?  If Len(Dir(Pict)) > 0 Then Pict = Dir(Pict)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would help you:

```
Function FunctionGetFileName(FullPath As String)
Dim StrFind As String
    Do Until Left(StrFind, 1) = "\"
        iCount = iCount + 1
        StrFind = Right(FullPath, iCount)
            If iCount = Len(FullPath) Then Exit Do
    Loop
    FunctionGetFileName = Right(StrFind, Len(StrFind) - 1)
End Function
```