# paste image excel

Tags: excel, vba

I can successfully browse to and insert an image in the selected cell and have it resize as desired.  The issue is when I email the excel file to asscoiates, the images do not display because the path to the image file is not on their pc.  Here is the code I am using, calling it out with a keyboard shortcut Ctrl-i:

```
Public Sub InsertAndResize()
CellWidth = Selection.Width
CellHeight = Selection.Height
CellLeft = Selection.Left
CellTop = Selection.Top
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert( _
Application.GetOpenFilename( _
"JPG picture files (*.jpg),*.jpg", , "Select the picture")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Width = CellWidth
If Selection.ShapeRange.Height > CellHeight Then Selection.ShapeRange.Height = CellHeight
With Selection
    .Height = Selection.ShapeRange.Height - 4
    .Width = Selection.ShapeRange.Width - 4
    .Left = CellLeft + ((CellWidth - .Width) / 2)
    .Top = CellTop + ((CellHeight - .Height) / 2)
End With
End Sub
```

How do I insert/paste an image into a cell and eliminate or break the link to the source file so others can see it when they open a copy of the file?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
Steve

Comment: Use the `worksheet.shapes.addPicture()` method instead of `Pictures.Insert()`.  Set `LinktoFile` to False and `SaveWithDocument` to True.

Comment: Oh there's a possible duplicate `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609631/remove-path-from-the-file-name-of-a-picture-in-vba`

Answer (score 0):

You may do this to clean up the sheet from `image links` by linking the image to the `cell name`

- [Further info can be found here:](https://superuser.com/questions/117623/inserting-a-jpg-picture-into-a-cell-in-microsoft-excel-2007)